# javascript typecasting error when updating global variable via html

Tags: javascript, html

I was working on a program in javascript which included the modulo operator. Since [the modulo operator is bugged in js](https://web.archive.org/web/20090717035140if_/javascript.about.com/od/problemsolving/a/modulobug.htm), I created my own function to do so:

```
function mod(a, b){
    return ((a%b)+b)%b;
}
```

In one of the larger function of my program, I call on my modulo function, using a given parameter as a and a global variable as b. However, this causes the mod function to spit out incorrect results. Here is a simplified version of my program which recreates the bug (note, the 7 I use as parameter is arbitrary, the bug works with any number):

```js
let global = 6;

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("global").onchange = function(){
        global = this.value;
        testing(7);
    }
}

function testing(param){
    mod(param, global);
}

function mod(a, b){
    let result = ((a%b)+b)%b;
    console.log("mod of ", a, " and ", b, " is:", result);
    return result;
}
```

```html
<input id="global" type="number" min="1" value="6">
```

Using both Firefox' console and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hms52ogj/2/), it appears as if the second parameter, b, is a string instead of a number. I have no idea why though.
Why does Javascript incorrectly think I am using a string, and why does this cause such weird results? How can I fix this other than first typecasting the parameters to ints?

Comment: The issue you are experiencing is caused by the fact that the value property of an input element returns a string, even if the type attribute is set to number. This means that when you assign the value of the input element to the global variable, it is a string, not a number.

Comment: Because `HTMLInputElement.prototype.value` _does_ result in a string, _always_. You want `HTMLInputElement.prototype.valueAsNumber`. All this discussion about the modulo operator is completely irrelevant. Your question can be reduced to _“Why is `typeof document.getElementById("global").value === "string"`?”_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is likely because the value property of an input element with a type of "number" returns a string, even if the value is a number. In your code, you are using this value as the global variable, which is then passed as the b parameter to the mod function. When the modulo operator % is used with a string value, it is treated as a string rather than a number, which can lead to unexpected results.

To fix this issue, you can convert the value of the input element to a number before assigning it to the global variable. One way to do this is to use the parseInt function, which converts a string to an integer.

Here is an example of how you can update your code to fix this issue, could you try:

```
let global = 6;

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("global").onchange = function(){
        global = parseInt(this.value, 10); // convert the value to a number
        testing(7);
    }
}

function testing(param){
    mod(param, global);
}

function mod(a, b){
    let result = ((a%b)+b)%b;
    console.log("mod of ", a, " and ", b, " is:", result);
    return result;
}

<input id="global" type="number" min="1" value="6">
```

OR:

```
let global = 6;

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("global").onchange = function(){
        global = Number(this.value); // convert the value to a number
        testing(7);
    }
}

function testing(param){
    mod(param, global);
}

function mod(a, b){
    let result = ((a%b)+b)%b;
    console.log("mod of ", a, " and ", b, " is:", result);
    return result;
}

<input id="global" type="number" min="1" value="6">
```